# Pitch dark (Earth Hour remembrance)

Tags: code-golf

Your goal is simple: the program must turn the screen of your computer **totally black**.

After the program is started, the screen must quickly turn completely black, and remain so until the program is exited (any key, or alt+F4, mouse movement, etc.), after which things should turn back to normal. So **shutting down the computer or turning the power of the monitor off is NOT allowed**.
Not a single non-black pixel should be visible during this time, not even a blinking cursor.

The user should not do any preparation (moving the mouse outside the screen, disconnecting cables, etc. or user input after the program started), just start the program.

You can safely assume the computer has only one monitor attached. We also assume a standard desktop or notebook computer, because doing it on a specific device without a normal monitor would be too simple.

If you use any external resources (a black image, a GUI file, etc.) their size in bytes is added to your code size.

It's OK if it only works on one OS family, or if it requires opengl etc., but requiring a very specific hardware configuration is frowned upon.

Your source code must be written in a programming language, not just a configuration file some other program (like a screen saver) will use.

Comment: That won't work on screens with stuck pixels...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel : you can safely assume a screen in perfect working condition. Otherwise we could object other questions in the style of "what if a transistor in my ALU is burned out and my computer cannot do any floating point math?" :)

Comment: What hardware can we assume is available on the computer?

Comment: @AJMansfield : assume a standard off-the shelf PC with a VGA/HDMI video card and common peripherals. As I don't have experience in mobile phones, I would like to remain in the world of personal computers, otherwise someone would surprise me with a singe instruction which turns off the screen of a specific brand of mobile phone.

Comment: Fun fact: on screens that use neither CRT nor dynamic contrast, this will use slightly more electricity!

Comment: real world application: Astronomy! http://lists.apple.com/archives/Carbon-dev/2008/May/msg00005.html

Comment: @minitech You might be right, but almost everyone has LED or LCD screens. LCD screens work by passing electricity behind the crystals. And LEDs are tiny LEDs inside. The black color on those can be made by turning off the LEDs.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Oh, right, those fancy LED screens. My comment refers specifically to [TN LCDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display#Twisted_nematic_.28TN.29), the most common as far as standalone LCD monitors go, I believe.

Comment: All of the answers are automatically disqualified—one of my monitors has a pixel whose red value is always 255!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat see comment number 1

Comment: This appears to be one of the few questions on this site with a [Latex answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14797/21955) !

Comment: Could HTML qualify?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Bash, 28 <sub><sup>or 12</sup></sub>

Assuming default installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

Automatically starts the screensaver, which is a black screen by default.

**Edit**: As suggested by @Glenn Randers-Pehrson, here's one with 12 bytes

```
/*/*/gn*d -a
```

Note that this may not work if you have another file on your system that satisfies this name, say `/tmp/1/gnd`. <sub><sup>But it's code-golf, who cares?</sup></sub>

---

Check out [my other bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26793/12205) if you don't use Gnome screensaver!

Comment: The kind of answer that makes you think: 'Why on earth didn't I think of that?'. :)

Comment: That's not really clearing the screen using bash.

Comment: "Your source code must be written in a programming language, not just a configuration file some other program (like a screen saver) will use."

Comment: @hannes karppila I did not change any configuration file that any other program will use. I only *started* another program, which most bash scripts do (unless written in pure bash)

Comment: @ace, Golfed: /*/*/gn*d instead of gnome-screensaver-command will save about 16 bytes (idea by mniip)

Comment: Works perfectly for me.

Comment: But your script does use `gnome-screensaver-command`, and as the OP says "If you use any external resources (a black image, a GUI file, etc.) their size in bytes is added to your code size." you should add its size.

Comment: @Mr Lister so if my bash script uses `echo`, `cat`, `clear` etc., do I need to add their sizes as well? And in fact, since some consider this invalid, I came up with another answer, which I linked to, which does not involve calling a screensaver.

Comment: @ace Technically at least some of what you listed aren't programs that are being called.  They're shell built-ins, but I'd agree that gnome-screensaver-command is not an external resource.  I would consider it more equivalent to calling an external library in C (like using winsock2.h on Windows)

Comment: While I do have some doubts about your answer abiding the rules, I think this much stretching of the rules can be tolerated here.

Answer (score 31):

**Assembly** (bootloader) 131 chars / 512 bytes compiled (actually smaller, but bootsector must be 512 bytes long.)

It is a simple boot loader. When computer starts, BIOS will load it from disk (floppy). Then it enters into graphics mode and just hangs. When user presses the power button, program will end and computer will enter to mode where is was before running program.

Tested with VirtualBox.

It will compile with nasm:

```
nasm -f bin file.asm -o start.img
```

Source code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]
cli
mov AX,0x0
mov SS,AX
mov SP,0x9000
sti
mov AH,0x0
mov AL,0x13
int 0x10
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: How to run on VirtualBox: (compile using nasm), new VM, Type: Other, version: Other/Unknown, no hard drive. Next up go to the VM's settings, select Storage, right click in the list, and select "Add Floppy Controller". Mount the compiled img file to the floppy drive. Save, and then you can run it. Enjoy!

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing as a dos program, but you were faster. Basically the only thing I remember of assembler from waaay back :)

Comment: Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: Why the `cli` and `sti`? Moves to `SS` automatically disable interrupts for the duration of the next instruction, and `AX` won't be changed if an interrupt happens before `MOV SS,AX`. Also, why not `MOV AX, 0x13` instead of two `MOV`s?

Comment: Younger me didn't know how to write code properly. Current me probably doesn't know either.

Answer (score 15):

## QBASIC (31)

```
SCREEN 7
WHILE INKEY$=""
WEND
```

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I finally found a use for my windows 3.1 vm.

Comment: Wow seeing that WEND brought back memories

Comment: @user973810 You mean [QB64](http://www.qb64.net/).

Answer (score 14):

## Java : 165

Simple Java, just creates a fullscreen black frame. To exit you have to Alt+Tab back to the console and Ctrl-C, but that seems simple enough.

```java
import java.awt.*;class B{public static void main(String[]a){Frame f=new Frame();f.setExtendedState(6);f.setUndecorated(1>0);f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);f.show();}}

// line breaks below

import java.awt.*;
class B{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        Frame f=new Frame();
        f.setExtendedState(6);
        f.setUndecorated(1>0);
        f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Applesoft ][ BASIC (17)

```
1 HGR2:GET X:TEXT
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually 17 bytes...I think it might be less.  If I remember correctly, Applesoft tokenized its keywords, so that each keyword was actually one byte...so this one may be significantly shorter.  It's +1 either way.

Answer (score 11):

## Bash - 57 <s>26</s>

```
C=/s*/*/*/*/b*ess;(A=$(cat $C);echo 0;cat;echo $A)|tee $C
```

On a laptop this will set the screen backlight brightness to 0 via `/sys/class/backlight`, on a tablet or phone this will set the screen led brightness to 0 via `/sys/class/leds`

Comment: “and remain so until the program is exited (any key, or alt+F4, mouse movement, etc.), after which things should turn back to normal”

Comment: `Fn+F6`, `Fn+<up arrow>` and many other key combinations fall into "any key" and "etc.", and those are one of the many to put the light back as it was.

Comment: @minitech Oh. Well, fixed...

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. If I do "C=/s*/*/*/*/b*ess;(A=$(cat $C);echo 0;cat;echo $A)|tee $C" from the bash prompt I get cat: /s*/*/*/*/b*ess: No such file or directory
tee: /s*/*/*/*/b*ess: No such file or directory

Comment: @Lembik I would assume that you don't have any brightness controllers or those present are lacking drivers. Mind pastebinning `find /sys/class/{backlight,leds}/*/` ?

Comment: @mnip find /sys/class/{backlight,leds}/*/
find: ‘/sys/class/backlight/*/’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/sys/class/leds/*/’: No such file or directory

Comment: @mnip find /sys/class/{backlight,leds}/
/sys/class/backlight/
/sys/class/leds/

Answer (score 8):

I know this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) but I couldn't resist.

Just make sure you don't have any browser windows open (in this case, Chrome);

Execute this **PitchBlack.bat (<s>31</s> 24 bytes)**:

```
chrome --kiosk file:///1
```

If placed in the same directory of your *Chrome.exe* file, this batch will execute Chrome in **kiosk mode** and it will open a file called **/1 (<s>49</s> <s>41</s> 34 bytes)** in fullscreen:

```
<body bgcolor=0 style=cursor:none>
```

*Et voilà!*

**Total byte count: <s>80</s> <s>72</s> 58**
Thanks to @ace :)

To exit the program, you must go for a classic **ALT+F4**; You don't actually have to do any preparation *after* the program starts (neither before, you just have to place `/1` and the batch file), so it's fine with the rules.

Please note that if you get your cursor towards the screen borders, it *may* become visible. The OP didn't say this was not allowed, since

> After the program is started, the screen must quickly turn completely black, and remain so until the program is exited (any key, or alt+F4, **mouse movement**, etc.), after which things should turn back to normal.

So this should be totally ok! :P

Comment: Maybe something like `chrome --kiosk 'data:text/html,<style>body{background:#000;cursor:none;}</style>'` can work without additional file?

Comment: Means when using `file:` shceme you get no URL bar visible, but with `data:` scheme there is URL bar?

Comment: On my system `chromium-browser --kiosk 'data:text/html,<style>body{background:#000;cursor:none;}</style>` starts almost-fullscreen Chromium with the black page without any bars.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu and Chromium 34.0, it works with `file:///1` if the html is saved as `/1`, and the html file can be shortened to `<body bgcolor=0 style=cursor:none>`

Comment: @ace great one! :D

Comment: I think you should use `chrome` in your answer rather than `chromium`

Answer (score 7):

## C# - <s>211</s> <s>202</s> <s>200</s> <s>196</s> 179 bytes

```c#
using System.Windows.Forms;class A{static void Main(){Cursor.Hide();new Form{BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Black,WindowState=(FormWindowState)2,FormBorderStyle=0}.ShowDialog();}}
```

Hides the cursor and shows a full-screen black window. Can be closed with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

**Un-golfed code**:

```c#
using System.Windows.Forms;
class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Cursor.Hide();
        new Form
        {
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
            WindowState = (FormWindowState)2, // FormWindowState.Maximized
            FormBorderStyle = 0 // FormBorderStyle.None
        }.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

I don't need to cast to `FormBorderStyle`, because that's not necessary if the integer is `0`.

Comment: You can replace `System.Drawing.Color.Black`, `FormWindowState.Maximized`, `FormWindowState.Maximized` and `FormBorderStyle.None` with their corresponding values.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Thanks, I updated the FormWindowState and the FormBorderStyle! I couldn't update the Color, because that's not an enum.

Comment: Try `Color.Black`. It should work right away. Or `BackColor=This.ForeColor`, which MIGHT work too.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: The first doesn't work because I didn't add `using System.Drawing;`, and the second doesn't work because I set the variable values inside brackets.

Comment: Try `using System;` then `new Windows.Forms.Form` and `BackColor=Drawing.Color.Black`. It __MIGHT__ work! And save a few bytes.

Comment: Nevermind, it will not help :S But I really like the solution.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: That doesn't work, and even if it would work, I wouldn't save bytes, because I would have to add `Windows.Forms.Form` before `FormWindowState` and before `FormBorderStyle`.

Comment: (It works in VB.NET!)

Comment: This sounds like a stupid question but I must ask it: Won't it work if instead of `BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Black` you put `BackColor="#FF000000"`? That is the ARGB representation of the color as a string. I don't have the C# compiler to test it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: How about `new System.Drawing.Color`? I think that should work, even considering alpha. Would save one character. =)

Comment: @minitech: No, that does not work: I got the default color instead of black.

Comment: You can use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to save two more bytes. Just change `new Form(){` to `new Form{`.

Comment: @ŞafakGür: Thanks, I updated my answer!

Comment: I think `ShowDialog` would work instead of `Application.Run`.

Comment: @KendallFrey: Indeed, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## C# <s>175</s> <s>171</s> 167

```cs
class P{static void Main(){SendMessage(65535,274,61808,2);}[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]static extern int SendMessage(int a,int b,int c,int d);}
```

A lot of the answers here don't actually make the screen *black*: on an LCD screen, the backlight remains on and bleeds through, leaving you with a darkish grey.

This little snippet actually tells Windows to turn off the screen, the same as what the inactivity timer does (Note: this doesn't violate the "no power off" rule because it really just causes the monitor to go into standby. *Most* monitors will turn back on when input is resumed. Also, that rule's intention seems to be to make sure the program can turn it back on - see below.)

Move the mouse or press a key to turn the screen back on.

Monitor power off adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/713519/1030702

Comment: "So __shutting down the computer or turning the power of the monitor off is NOT allowed__."

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I have provided my justification. "until the program is exited (any key, or alt+F4, mouse movement, etc.), after which things should turn back to normal. So shutting..." - the rule's *intention* has been satisfied. This will "turn it back on". Leaving aside the intention, it also satifies the *literal* meaning, since, despite Microsoft's terminology, this isn't really turning it *off* (timeouts on projectors, etc., aside), it's placing it into *standby*.

Answer (score 4):

## Python / Pygame <strike>199</strike> <strike>127</strike> <strike>125</strike> 92

```
from pygame import*;display.set_mode((9,9),-1<<31);mouse.set_visible(0)
while 1:event.pump()
```

Thanks to some tips from ace.

Comment: Since ALT+F4 counts, I'd take also ^C counts, so you can skip a lot of bytes at the end.

Comment: For ^C to work you need to be focused on the terminal, and in the program the pygame window is always focused due to pygame.FULLSCREEN

Edit: One alternative would be to leave the program with no exit, which would require spamming the keyboard till your OS notices something is wrong.

Comment: You can save some bytes by using `from pygame import*` instead. Also, I don't think `fill((0,0,0))` is necessary since the default color is black. Then you can remove `s` altogether. I don't think `display.flip()` is needed either. Also, use one space for indentation instead of 4 can save you more spaces. Finally, instead of `FULLSCREEN` and `KEYDOWN`, you can use their numeric values, namely `-1<<31` (-2147483648) and `2` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

## Amiga assembly

ASM-One - <del>228</del> 219 chars, 172 bytes compiled (168 bytes optimized)

It's been 20 years since I last coded a single line in Amiga assembly, so bear with me. :-)

The Amiga was a bit more involved than the PC in terms of setting up a blank screen, so tried to get rid of as much setup and teardown as possible. There's no disabling of interrupts or multitasking; no double WaitTOF; no view replacement; etc. I wouldn't even have written this for the quickest and dirtiest demo. Which means this:

- is bad practice
- may not be entirely safe
- may not always work
- even with those disclaimers, probably has stupid mistakes owing to 20 years of neglected assembly.

... although it's been tested on emulated A500 and A1200, with or without fast memory. Compiles to a standard executable. Mouse click exits.

```
l=$dff080
 move.l 4,a6
 lea g,a1
 jsr -408(a6)
 move.l d0,a1
 move.l 38(a1),d4
 jsr -412(a6)
 move.l #c,l
w:btst #6,$bfe001
 bne w
 move.l d4,l
 rts
g:dc.b "graphics.library",0
 SECTION d,DATA_C
c:dc 256,512,384,0,-1,-2
```

Less golfed:

```
COP1LC equ $dff080

    move.l  $4, a6          ; ExecBase
    lea     gfxname, a1
    jsr     -408(a6)        ; OpenLibrary (old, hence no need for clearing d0)
    move.l  d0, a1
    move.l  38(a1), d4      ; store copper list
    jsr     -414(a6)        ; CloseLibrary
                            ; Yeah, if I had a penny for the times I saw that left out
                            ; but I just... can't...

    move.l  #copper,COP1LC  ; write copper list

wait:
    btst    #6, $bfe001     ; Check mouse click
    bne     wait

    move.l  d4, COP1LC      ; restore copper list
    rts

gfxname:
    dc.b    "graphics.library", 0

    SECTION data, DATA_C
copper:
    dc.w $0100, $0200       ; disable bitplanes
    dc.w $0180, $0000       ; color 0 = black
    dc.w $ffff, $fffe       ; end
```

Comment: Aaaah, the memories! Love it!

Comment: Yeah, this was more of an excuse for a nostalgia trip than a real attempt at code golf - Amiga assembly will rarely compete with Perl or Python in terms of character count. Although I was a bit surprised it couldn't beat C# or Java. :)

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, <strike>7</strike> 6

```
Shade(Ymin,Ymax
```

Works both in the terminal (home screen) or as a program. Pressing `ON` or most other buttons returns to the terminal/home screen.

Comment: Can be one byte smaller (and work even if the graph screen window is changed) as `Shade(Ymin,Ymax`.

Comment: @ThomasKwa You're right, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

### sh/X11 on Arch Linux, 26

```
b=/b*/*ht;$b =0;read;$b =7
```

Comment: you can probably shave a few chars with an alias and maybe using `-set` for both

Comment: Use `xbacklight = 0` and `xbacklight + 7`.

Comment: 29 bytes: `x=xbacklight;$x +0;read;$x +7`

Comment: @nyuszika7h: Thanks! (Got it to 28, too!)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 37

Uses `unclutter` to hide the mouse pointer and a fullscreen session of `xterm` to black the screen. The cursor will reappear for a moment if you move it, but if you leave it alone the screen will be black until you press Ctrl+C.

It will take a few seconds for the mouse cursor to disappear (as long as you don't move it). If this isn't fast enough, add the `-grab` option to `unclutter` for an additional 6 chars.

```
unclutter&xterm -fu -bg black -e yes ''
```

**WARNING:**  this will leave a process of `unclutter` running even after you press Ctrl+C, use `killall unclutter` to stop it.

### Explanation

`unclutter &` launches `unclutter`. The `&` is there so we can get on with the next command instead of waiting for this one to terminate.

`xterm -fullscreen` launches XTerm, whose background is black by default.

The `-e yes ''` option causes XTerm to run `yes ''`, thereby printing the empty string forever. This serves to hide the terminal cursor, and also provides the Ctrl+C functionality.

Comment: Screen gets completely white in my system.

Comment: @Vi. that means your XTerm background colour is white.

Comment: You can abbreviate "-fullscreen" to "-fu", and use "-bg black" to force black background color regardless of user preferences.

Comment: You can remove the spaces around `&` to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, 31 (or 52)

On a TTY, use the following script (assuming your default TTY background is black, which is true at least for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
setterm -foreground black
clear
```

Your TTY would still be fully functional even after using  this script :)

If this isn't allowed, use the following (52 bytes):

```
x='setterm -foreground'
$x black
clear
read
$x white
```

And press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to terminate the script.

Special thanks to @nyuszika7h.

Comment: For the second case: `x='setterm -foreground';$x black;clear;read;$x white` (52 bytes).

Answer (score 3):

## Commodore 64 (16 bytes)

```
ROL $A903
BRK
STA $D020
STA $D011
JSR $FF8A
JMP ($032C)
```

It has been more than 20 years since I used Turbo Assembler, so I can only provide source for use in VICE's monitor. Assemble this at $032C and `save`[1] through $033B. `Reset` and `LOAD"PITCHDARK",8,1`. Hit good ol' `Runstop+Restore`[2] to get back to normal.

How does it work?

Here's the true source:

```
032C 2E 03      .BY 2E 03
032E A9 00      LDA #$00
0330 8D 20 D0   STA $D020   ; set border color  
0333 8D 11 D0   STA $D011   ; set VIC blanking mode
0336 20 15 FD   JSR $FF8A   ; reset the vectors we trampled
0339 6C 2C 03   JMP ($032C) ; call the real CLALL
```

$032C is the [kernal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KERNAL) `CLALL` or "Close All Channels And Files" vector. As part of its cleanup, the BASIC `LOAD` command does a `CLR` which in turn calls `CLALL`. We replace the `CLALL` vector with a pointer to our own routine immediately after the vector. We set the border to black and cover the screen with the border, and then call `RESTOR` at $FF8A. The last vector replaced by `RESTOR` is `SAVE` at $0332-0333 which means the last 8 bytes are undisturbed. We then exit via the restored `CLALL` vector to continue `LOAD`'s execution.

Thanks for this, it was fun trip down memory lane, relearning how to do an autorun program :)

[1] use save and not bsave so that load with ,1 works correctly
[2] Escape + PageUp in x64, probably.

Answer (score 2):

## ZX Spectrum Basic (29 bytes)

```
1 FOR x=0 TO 255
2 FOR y=0 TO 175
3 PLOT x,y
4 NEXT y
5 NEXT x
```

Iterates over the screen, plotting black pixels which are automatically cleared when the program finishes.

<sub><sup>The ZX Spectrum's edition of basic uses single bytes as commands and no newlines, if counting displayed characters you get 61 chars.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

## Processing, 113

```java
void setup(){noCursor();size(displayWidth, displayHeight);background(0);}boolean sketchFullScreen(){return true;}
```

I tried putting the code above onto draw() to save some bytes, but it didn't work. Press Alt-F4 to quit.

Answer (score 2):

### Lua + LÖVE (50)

```
love.mouse.setVisible()love.window.setFullscreen""
```

Both functions are supposed to take a boolean argument, yet this works.

Answer (score 2):

### QBasic, 9 bytes

```
CLS:SLEEP
```

`CLS` clears the screen, `SLEEP` without any arguments holds execution until a key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 15 bytes

```
XSCREEN 4
EXEC.
```

Pressing START or SELECT will end the program.

`XSCREEN 4` sets the display mode to show a 320*480 image spanning both screens. This should clear everything, so an `ACLS` is not required. `EXEC.` makes the code repeat by constantly running the program in slot 0.
I wasn't able to do `XSCREEN 4EXEC.` because you can't have a number directly before `E`

Answer (score 1):

## Sinclair BASIC - 28 chars

```
BORDER 0:PAPER 0:CLS:PAUSE 0
```

The thing about Sinclair BASIC was each keyword had it's own character code (taking up one byte), so this would actually take up 13 bytes including spaces.

Comment: Does this return the screen to normal after finishing?

Comment: @kitcar2000 - Thinking about it, no. I'd probably add ":NEW" at the end as a quick and dirty reset, taking it up to 32 chars/15 bytes

Comment: I think that it is only 10 bytes (12 with `:NEW`) as the commands are single bytes rather than a collection of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 23 bytes

Runs forever until the program is force-killed with START or SELECT. This makes both screens *completely black*, going so far to disable 3D (thus turning off the 3D LED on o3DS.)

```
ACLS:XSCREEN 3@L GOTO@L
```

Answer (score 1):

## Most POSIX compatible shells (at least `bash` and `zsh`), 21

Needs to be run on a tty

```
tput civis;clear;read
```

First command hides the cursor, second command clears the screen (duh) and third command reads a line of text

Answer (score 0):

## BASH - 14 chars

`pmset sleepnow` does the job!

(typed into my Mac's Terminal)

Comment: You should specify the OS and/or other prerequisites in your answer.

Comment: @ace answer edited :)

Comment: Doesn't sleep shut the monitor down?

Answer (score 0):

## Bash: 48 characters

```
eval xrandr\ --output\ DP1\ --{off,auto}\;read\;
```

CW because not clear whether it qualifies due to the way it works:

- The produced black screen is real power saving: it cuts off information sending to display 1.
- Many computer displays when detect signal loss, will temporarily or periodically show their own notice.

(Note that DP1 is the first *connected* display. If you have a laptop, its embedded display is eDP1.)

Answer (score 0):

## [HTML Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) (.hta), 102 bytes

```html
<HTA:APPLICATION CAPTION=no innerborder=0 border=dialog scroll=0 windowstate=maximize><body bgcolor=0>
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-80 BASIC, 5 bytes

```
ZOOM OUT
ZOOM OUT
GRIDON
```

Answer (score 0):

## Chip-8, 0 bytes

> [T]he original Chip-8 interpreter began execution from 0x01FC. The interpreter includes two permanent Chip-8 instructions at this location that are always executed at the start of every programme. The first of these, 0x00E0, clears the display RAM by setting all the bits to zero. The second, 0x004B, calls a machine language routine within the interpreter that switches the VIP’s display on.

Source: http://laurencescotford.co.uk/?p=75